# including a pdf as an image rather than png format

Tags: discussion, support

In some cases, it seems the pdf output of Tikz is more elegant and cleaner than capturing the image via screen capture softwares (e.g. Texmaker). Is there a way to upload the pdf directly rather than an image (i.e. `.jpeg` or`.png`) in the website? Image upload button allows uploading only images not pdf.

Comment: Could you edit here to make it clear you are talking about the website?

Comment: Web browsers don't work with PDFs, they need raster images. You can of course convert your PDF to PNG without doing a screen grab: we've got a number of meta questions in this area.

Comment: the actual post is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269586/including-a-pdf-as-an-image-rather-than-png-format?noredirect=1#comment647367_269586 but I don't know why it has been migrated.

Comment: The way the question reads here it seemed to be about TeX not about using TeX-sx, so I migrated to the main site. However, you edit there makes it clear that you are really talking about interaction with the website, so I've 'killed' the migration.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The update has been made.